# How do I use a timestamp as input in python?

Tags: python, input, timestamp

I need to use a 2d array of timestamp object as input for a function that will parse the array to find the date ranges. A small example from the array:

```
[[1979-06-05 00:00:00, 1979-06-06 00:00:00], [2000-06-05 00:00:00, 2000-06-06 00:00:00]]
```

How do I structure the input of this array to indicate these are timestamp objects without getting a syntax error? The input must be timestamps.

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are already lots of answers on datetime and how to get time deltas with python here on stackoverflow.

Comment: I've taken a look at the posts about datetime but none seem to be about input. I've tried inputting the array with the datetime.datetime function but python won't take it.

Comment: Next time please be more specific (as the fellow stackoverflowers do want to answer but can't) https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask please follow this guideline. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **list** that you've provided is not valid unless like stated down is a string.

Now after that, we can use a special method from the `datetime.datetime` module called `.strptime` that will convert (provided that we give it a format) the string to a datetime object. Then we can do a ***simple conversion***.

```
from datetime import *
lista = [['1979-06-05 00:00:00', '1979-06-06 00:00:00'],
         ['2000-06-05 00:00:00', '2000-06-06 00:00:00']]

new_list = []

for i in lista:
    temp_list = []
    for j in i:
        temp_list.append(datetime.strptime(j, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
    new_list.append(temp_list)


# to get timedelta of the 2 - 1 item

print(new_list[0][1]-new_list[0][0])
```

You'll need to be more specific about the algorithm if you want the time delta for all items.